# Android Download manager shows complete but later shows unsuccessful

Tags: android, webview

https://github.com/kuropen/WebViewImageSaveSample/blob/master/src/org/kuropen/webviewimagesavesample/WebViewFragment.java
 Whats wrong in this?
download manager shows image download complete but later on shows Unsuccessful...

Comment: If you have question regarding particular library then you need to raise an issue over there.

Comment: its not a library :)